# Pyspark read csv with schema, header check, and store corrupt records

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to use pyspark csv reader with the following criteria:

- Read csv according to datatypes in schema
- Check that column names in header and schema matches
- Store broken records in a new field

Here is what I have tried.

```
file: ab.csv
------
a,b
1,2
3,four
```

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
DDL = "a INTEGER, b INTEGER"
df = spark.read.csv('ab.csv', header=True, schema=DDL, enforceSchema=False,
                    columnNameOfCorruptRecord='broken')
print(df.show())
```

Output:

```
+----+----+
|   a|   b|
+----+----+
|   1|   2|
|null|null|
+----+----+
```

This command does not store the corrupted records. If I add `broken` to
the schema and remove header validation the command
works with a warning.

```
DDL = "a INTEGER, b INTEGER, broken STRING"
df = spark.read.csv('ab.csv', header=True, schema=DDL, enforceSchema=True, 
                    columnNameOfCorruptRecord='broken')
print(df.show())
```

Output:

```
WARN  CSVDataSource:66 - Number of column in CSV header is not equal to number of fields in the schema:
 Header length: 2, schema size: 3
CSV file: file:/// ... /ab.csv
+----+----+------+
|   a|   b|broken|
+----+----+------+
|   1|   2|  null|
|null|null|3,four|
+----+----+------+
```

Is this intended behavior or is there a bug that breaks the first example?
Is there a better way to do this?

One more thing. I want to process well-formed fields in corrupted records
to get a dataframe like this.

```
+--+----+------+
| a|   b|broken|
+--+----+------+
| 1|   2|  null|
| 3|null|3,four|
+--+----+------+
```

Should I make an extra step post reading to get that, or is there some
option I have missed to be more permissive.

Answer (score 2):

Like @deo said, when using `columnNameOfCorruptRecord`, Spark will implicitly create the column before dropping it during parsing. In order to keep the column, you need to explicitly add it to your schema. Note that this behavior also depends on what `mode` you specify when reading.

See this snippet  for the `mode` param in the Spark [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html):

> PERMISSIVE : when it meets a corrupted record, puts the malformed string into a field configured by columnNameOfCorruptRecord, and sets other fields to null. To keep corrupt records, an user can set a string type field named columnNameOfCorruptRecord in an user-defined schema. If a schema does not have the field, it drops corrupt records during parsing. A record with less/more tokens than schema is not a corrupted record to CSV. When it meets a record having fewer tokens than the length of the schema, sets null to extra fields. When the record has more tokens than the length of the schema, it drops extra tokens.

Answer (score 1):

That's the correct default behavior. 
If you are inferring a schema, it implicitly adds a columnNameOfCorruptRecord field in an output schema, otherwise you have to provide a string type field named columnNameOfCorruptRecord in an user-defined schema or change the column name like broken and add the same name to the schema.

There is no option process the data partially as you mentioned, for that to happen you need to write your own custom parser extending CSVFileFormat in spark. 
For list of all csvoptions, check
org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/csv/CSVOptions.scala

Comment: _If you are inferring a schema, it implicitly adds a columnNameOfCorruptRecord field in an output schema._
I just tested this. It did not add a column. It just dropped the record and put None in the fields (just as it did in my first example). I tested it by making a longer ab.csv file with mainly integers and lowering the sampling rate for infering the schema. `spark.read.csv('ab.csv', header=True, inferSchema=True, enforceSchema=False, columnNameOfCorruptRecord='broken', samplingRatio=0.1)`

Answer (score 1):

My team was struggling with the same issue so we checked the file and the format error was because there are some text with \n inside the data. However, it should be in \ " . So, when we checked the file using [Atom](https://atom.io/) we noticed the problem and then the solution was just force the reader to handle multi-lines.

```
df = spark.read.options(header=True,  sep='|').csv("my_csv_file", multiLine=True)
```